# Data Integration Superbadge - Step 9 Don't see invoices created on step 8

Tags: integration

trailblazers!

I passed the superbadge, but in fact I don't see the invoice_x records for projects created in Step 8.
Did anybody ensure the data really committed in Billing System or that is rather fake data provided ?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Invoice__x records are visible after the external data source connection is configured as described in the Synchronize Inbound Billing Data section of the [Superbadge](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/superbadges/superbadge_integration). This data comes from https://sb-integration-is.herokuapp.com/odata

[image]

After Validate and Sync, configure an indirect relationship from the external Invoice object to its parent project inside your org and ensure that invoice data is visible from its parent project detail page. The related list should only display the External ID, Bill Amount, and Bill Date.

[image]

If you are still not seeing the records, create a case with [Trailhead Support](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help?support=home#cfPanel)

Comment: Thanks, Anudeep!
I had to stress that I actually see the external object but no new records created are present there. That is why no related invoices for recently submitted to Billing System projects are available in related list.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Dmitry. As suspected by you, It appears that the OData endpoint given in the module is just to provide the fake data required for the module and to make the necessary configurations to map and expose fields from the Invoice table. I haven't been able to commit the Invoice__x records both from the UI and from the apex. DML operations give me the error Insert not allowed on invoices__x

Comment: Guess any additional data that we want to commit should be updated in heroku app - https://sb-integration-is.herokuapp.com/odata

Comment: Yes. But it seems there is no way to update that data.
Anyway you can check indirect lookup works fine if you changing projectRef of the project record to anyone which already exists in the Billing System. Note that related list for invoices works properly only in Classic, but not in Lightning. ) It's known issue for external objects in SF.
The most thing I was surprised - there no same issue discussion for outdated data in Billing System was googled by me, so I spent a time finding the issue in my code ).